# Azure Machine Learning FileDataSet Images - Shard/Split equally to nodes

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

How to read a portion of the Azure File Dataset(containing 1000 Images) in different train nodes. 
I want a sampling where all the images are covered.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.file_dataset.filedataset?view=azure-ml-py

I am looking for an option like tensorflow.dataset.shard().
 Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the the ParallelRunStep in Pipelines with FileDataset as input. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-parallel-run-step and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-contrib-pipeline-steps/azureml.contrib.pipeline.steps.parallelrunstep?view=azure-ml-py

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to train a model distributed on a cluster by passing a python script to all the nodes. I would like each node on the cluster to fetch a portion of the filedataset(As per my configured size). I wouldnt be able to use the parallelrunstep as a part of the python trainscript as it needs its own compute target, whats your opinion?

Comment: you should be able to use ParallelRunStep with a FileDataset for your scenario. make sure you point to your ParallelRunConfig to the compute target of your choice. For your scenario you may want to look at using Azure ML Compute clusters which is a serverless batch compute...